# GONE View behaves like INVISIBLE (android)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have set in XML `visibility="gone"` for the View. On the first click on the button (), the View should become visible (it works) `viewView.visibility = VISIBLE`. The second time you click on the button, the view should become "gone" again `viewView.visibility = GONE`.
But instead, the View doesn't disappear, but just becomes transparent, as if I had set `invisible` (look at the illustration from Layout Inspector).
How can I make the View truly "gone" like in the first frame?

[Please look the illustration from Layout Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ODl1.png)

Example code

```
var isVisible = false
    
val button = findViewById<View>(id.button)
val view = findViewById<View>(id.view)
    
button.setOnClickListener {
    view.visibility = if (isVisible) { GONE } else { VISIBLE }
    isVisible = !isVisible
}
```

And XML

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.4" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/design_default_color_secondary"
            android:visibility="gone" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your button logic and all seems to be working fine the issue is the layout inspector shows the view border or outline once you have made the view visible and then gone. if i am understanding this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're worrying too much about what's happening behind the scenes. Here's what happens if you add a `TextView` below that `View`:

[image: The Layout Inspector showing that the View is still full-size, but isn't affecting the rest of the layout]

Yes `view` still has its full size, but it's not actually affecting the layout. That's what `GONE` means - it's not visible, but it's also behaving as though it's not there, and everything else is laid out accordingly.

That doesn't mean the view *itself* has been recalculated with zero height or anything - for one thing, removing something doesn't *change its height*, right? It's just not in the layout anymore, so the *space it's taking up* is now zero. And there's also no reason to recalculate the height while the `View` isn't being displayed, it would be wasted work. It's just there, hanging around, waiting to be added to the layout again.

It's not like you can click it while it's in this state anyway, so what it's actually doing and how the system is managing stuff shouldn't be relevant. If your code *does* somehow rely on the `View` being "gone" in some sense (not present in the layout, garbage collected, zero width and height) then you'll have to account for determining that yourself, and whatever you're doing now isn't enough. You could check its `visibility` property remember!

---

Also just as an aside, be careful about what you name things - an ID called `view` and *especially* a variable called `view` inside a class that already has a `view` property is just asking for trouble. Same with a variable called `isVisible` being referenced in the scope of a `Button` and a `Fragment`, both of which have a property with the same name (and you'll get a warning about this one, `accidental override`)

It just leads to bugs when you accidentally reference the wrong thing. If these are just placeholder names you're using for your question, bear in mind people will copy your code to try and help you, and you're making work for them when they have to fix it. Not having a go or anything, just something to keep in mind!

Comment: Thx, but I have encountered this problem in a large project. There in ConstraintLayout I have three LinearLayouts, of which one is always "visible" and the rest are "gone". I switch between them, changing the visibility modes.
But the "gone" layout doesn't skip clicks on the visible layout that has buttons on it. Because of this, it is impossible to click on these buttons (clicks stop at the "gone" layout). So I'm looking for a way to set the "gone" parameter correctly so that the layout really disappears and doesn't overlap the buttons.
I hope I wrote it clearly, I sometimes use translator

Comment: @Random your writing is great, don't worry about it! But I can't replicate what you're seeing. I added two identical `LinearLayout`s inside that `ConstraintLayout`, both constrained to the top, and put a couple of buttons that display Toasts in the first layout. The other layout is declared after that, so it's technically "on top". With the first layout VISIBLE and the second GONE, I can still click the buttons. If I give the second layout an `elevation` and a `zTranslation` it still doesn't interfere. If I give it a click listener, that only fires while it's visible. It's like it's not there

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
button.setOnClickListener { v ->
            v?.let {
                val isViewVisible: Boolean = view.isVisible
                view.isVisible = !isViewVisible
            }
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood what I mean. I need the View to become truly "gone". He already becomes just invisible, but not "gone". Everything works fine, except that the view becomes not "gone", but invisible.